# calling iterator on list in constructor changes its final value?

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I am new to c++ but not to programming, and I am having a very baffling problem. I have class which in its constructor creates a list.

As you can see, I am printing out the final value of the list two different ways, which generally agree with each other: one using `list::end`, and the other using `list::back`. Then I call the constructor to this class in my main function, access the list that was created, and try to print the final value. The sample code is given below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;
class Process{
public:
    Process(int CB);  
    int CB;
};

Process::Process(int c){
    CB = c;  
}

class Event{
public:
    Event(Process *process);
    Process *process;   
};

Event::Event(Process *ps){
    process = ps;
}

typedef list<Event> EventList;

class DES{
public:
    DES(string originFile);
    EventList events;
};



DES::DES(string originFile){
    ifstream infile (originFile.c_str());
    string str;
    while (getline(infile, str)) {
        // output the line
        //cout << str << endl;
        istringstream iss(str);

        int AT,TC,CB,IO;
        if (!(iss >> AT >> TC>>CB>>IO)) { 
            cout<<"breaking out of while loop \n"; 
            break;
        } 
          Process p(CB);
          Event evt(&p);
        this->events.push_back(evt);

    }

  int cb =  this->events.back().process->CB;
EventList::iterator inserter2 = this->events.begin();
EventList::iterator inserter3 = this->events.end();

//inserter3--;

//cout<<"CB after while loop using List<>::end(): " <<inserter3->process->CB<<endl;
 //cout<<"CB after while loop using LIST<>::back "<<cb<<endl;

    infile.close();

}


int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
string inputFileName = argv[1];


DES des(argv[1]);
EventList::iterator b = des.events.end();
b--;
cout<<"CB at back of list in main: "<<b->process->CB<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

So here is where I get confused. The print statement in main should match the output of the print statements in teh constructor, since they are all simply printing the field `->process->CB` of the last element of the list. However, for some reason this only works when I uncomment the line `//EventList::iterator inserter2 = this->events.begin();` in my constructor. Similarly, if I keep that line and instead comment out the line `EventList::iterator inserter3 = this->events.end();`, it also doesn't work. Only when I construct an iterator on BOTH the end and beginning of the list does the correct value get printed out in main.

Can anyone shed some light on this odd behavior? I know it must be some simple misunderstanding due to my lack of familiarity with c++, but I have to admit this behavior seems a bit unnatural to me.

EDIT: here is the output with one of the iterators in the constructor commented out:

```
CB after while loop using List<>::end(): 10
CB after while loop using LIST<>::back 10
CB at back of list in main: 306496
```

And here is the output with both of the iterators in the constructor:

```
CB after while loop using List<>::end(): 10
CB after while loop using LIST<>::back 10
CB at back of list in main: 10
```

-Paul

Comment: Please edit your question, remove the isolated, individual code fragments, and replace them with a [mcve].

Comment: Also, please remove the comments.  We know what lines of code do.

Comment: I have edited the code some to remove the comments. How should I combine the code if they live in different files?

Comment: @Paul You combine them by copying and pasting the functions in one file and removing the redundant header files.  Plus you don't need input files -- hard code the data and test it.  You also don't need to keep specifying `this->` in your code.

Comment: Also, I think `Event` is highly important.  You're placing these objects in a vector, and if `Event` does not have the correct copy semantics, placing `Event` objects in a vector will become troublesome.  I wouldn't be the least bit surprised if this is the issue.

Comment: Thank you Paul, I realize now that this may be the issue. The Event object has as one of its fields a pointer to a Process object, which perhaps isn't getting copied over correctly. I put all of the relevant classes into one large file.

Comment: Going by your new comment, `Process p(AT,TC,CB,IO); Event evt(AT,&p,CREATED,READY);` means each `Event` takes a pointer to a single `Process` that changes each time. Try `Process p = new Process(AT,TC,CB,IO);` and see if things work better, then work out how to fix the memory leak this may cause.

Comment: Also - `Process p(AT,TC,CB,IO); Event evt(AT,&p,CREATED,READY);`  The `p` is a local variable, and you're using the address of a local here.  When that `{ }` block exits, that `p` is gone.

Comment: I just replaced those lines with `Process *p=new Process(AT,TC,CB,IO); Event evt(AT,p,CREATED,READY);`, and the error is gone. Thank you both!

Comment: @Paul - You don't need to use pointers if the `Process` object is that simple (containing only an `int`).

Comment: unforunately it is not that simple, this was just the simplified version I made for this post ;)

Comment: @Paul -  Please post the real `Process` and `Event` classes.  If the other members have sensible copy / assignment operators, then the `Process` and `Event` classes can still be placed in a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using / storing the address of a local here:

```
      Process p(AT,TC,CB,IO);
      Event evt(AT,&p,CREATED,READY);
```

Once the code block that declares `p` is exited, any referral to that pointer results in undefined behavior.

---

Since `Process` contains a simple `int`, you could just store copies of `Process` instead of using pointers.

```
class Process{
public:
    Process(int CB);  
    int CB;
};

class Event{
public:
    Event(const Process& process); 
    Process process;   
};

Event::Event(const Process& ps) : process(ps) {}
```

Then the first block of code would look like this:

```
      Process p(CB);
      Event evt(p);
```

or simply:

```
      Event evt(Process(CB));
```

This should at least rid you of the inconsistent results.

---

If you really do need a pointer, consider smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr` or if deemed necessary, `std::shared_ptr` instead of using raw pointers.

Comment: ok, assuming I need to store the process as a pointer rather than the object itself (because the actual class is much more complicated; I just simplified it for this post), what other solutions are there? @Ken Y-N metnioned above that I could use `Process p = new Process(AT,TC,CB,IO)` in order to store the pointer on the heap. Is there any other way to pass the pointer by value rather than by reference?

Comment: I mentioned it in my answer --  You can use a `std::shared_ptr` -- `typedef std::shared_ptr<Process> ProcessPtr; ProcessPtr  p = std::make_shared<Process>(AT, TC, CB, IO)`  -- When all referents to `p` are destroyed, the `delete` will be called automatically.

Comment: great, that is exactly what I needed. And it is reassuring to know that what I was thinking isn't impossible.

Comment: also, for now I will ignore the exact details of what was causing the iterators to somehow preserve the pointer value, and just chock it up to bad programming and move on.

Comment: The Most Vexing Parse: it vexes, and vexes, and vexes... ;-)